# Can we design a weighted least squares FFT with regularization? How to make it fast?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, soft-question, fourier-analysis

An FFT transforms a function to another function so that nothing is lost.

But what if we are okay with losing considerable portions of our function?

If we have a weight function, saying how important a fit shall be.

$$\min_{x}\|W(F^{-1}x-d)\|^2_2$$ with some extra regularization.

We can see that if $W = I$, we get that the unregularized solution is given by $$F^{-1}x = d \Leftrightarrow x = Fd$$

, the straight-forward Fourier transform.

But what if W is not the identity, but perhaps a binary function $\{0,1\}$ or lies in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Surely when W is binary you just drop the coordinates corresponding to 0s in W?

Comment: How do you mean drop coordinates?

Comment: If you mean just skip ahead those coordinates, that will give problems. Say we have an expected FFT operator size of $2^k$, then $n$ samples have w=0, if we just remove them we will be left with a vector of $2^k-n$ elements which is not a power of 2 for many n at all. We will then need to have special cases for FFT factorizations. Not feasible for many applications at all.

Comment: Ah I see I had not thought about the need to have things be a factor of two. It makes sense that unless you can drop from 2^K elements to 2^(K-1) you'd be unlikely to see significant speed ups without significantly specializing the FFT.